# After useEffect API call, state set by useState for json data being passed to a component as props returns empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still a beginner in React and I'm trying to use useEffect to fetch data from an API and then useState to set the state and then pass that state as props to a child component.

But in my child component, it appears as an empty array each time when I do console.log. I understand that on the first render the state of my initial `state` is an empty array []. But I've been trying to combat this and send the right JSON data but can't seem to do so.

I am trying to do this as I have multiple child components that I wanna send data to.

Below is a workaround I coded up with some digging around but doesn't work either:

```
   const api = 'url string'
    const [races, setRaces] = useState([]);
    const [races2, setRaces2] = useState([races]);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch(api)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((response) => setRaces(response));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (races.length) setRaces2(races);
  }, [races]);

<Child data={races2}
```

But this does not seem work to work either when I do console.log(props.data) in the child component.

This is how normally one would fetch data and try and send the data but in both cases, it's been the same.

```
   const api = 'url string'
    const [races, setRaces] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch(api)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((response) => setRaces(response));
  }, []);

<Child data={races}
```

Following is a rough flow diagram explaining what I wanna do:

[image: Use of state data architecture]

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Both of your snippets of code should at least *work*, I think - if they don't, the problem is somewhere else, such as with the API, or with `Child`

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is something that has been asked a quite a number of times on stack overflow and I've tried a few answers that match my scenario but they don't seem to work. Both times on first render the useStates empty initial [] array is sent forth as useEffect updates asynchronously.

Comment: Can you make a MCVE illustrating the problem you're encountering? There isn't enough information in the question to debug at the moment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've added a rough flow chart diagram to expain the same

Comment: You probably meant to do `const [races2, setRaces2] = useState(races);` instead of `const [races2, setRaces2] = useState([races]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this quick example.

Here is what the code does:

- Fetching the Data using UseEffect
- Storing into State
- Passing the State into Component as Props
- Fetching the Props and Displaying the data.

Code for App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(null);
  // * Init on Page Load
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTitle();
  }, []);

  const fetchTitle = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setTitle(data.title); //Setting the response into state
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildComponent data={title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code for ChildComponent.js

```js
export default function ChildComponent({ data }) {
  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
```

[image]

I created this Codesandbox. This might help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-lumiere-cg66nt

Comment: Thank you @MC Naveen it worked, it still sends a null initally but I am using conditionals on my child component to filter through that

Comment: Here, fetchTitle function is doing two things, fetching data and setting state, is there any better way of maintaining SRP here?

Answer (score 0):

Array and  object are referential data types, passing as array dependency will not re-run side effect. `useEffect` dependencies should be primitive data type (string, number, boolean,undefined or null).

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (races.length) setRaces2(races);

  }, [races.length])// Dependencies must be primitive data type not referencial.
```

Comment: this isn't true at all. it does a === check on the values provided to the dependency array. Arrays and objects will always return true when a different actual object is passed in. Checking for only the length here would fail to run the effect if the length stayed the same but the actual object inside were different.